# How do I create an axis label for my chart?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, devexpress

I have the following code to produce a bar chart using [@devexpress/dx-react-chart-material-ui](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/chart/docs/):

```
import React from 'react'
import { Chart, ArgumentAxis, ValueAxis, BarSeries } from '@devexpress/dx-react-chart-material-ui';


const data = [
  { label: 'Foobar', value: 58 },
  { label: 'Bazplugh', value: 37 },
  // etc...
]

const MyChart = () => (
    <Chart data={data} rotated={true}>
      <ValueAxis />
      <ArgumentAxis />
      <BarSeries argumentField="label" valueField="value" barWidth={0.8} />
    </Chart>
)
```

and it renders a bar chart that looks pretty good:

[image: bar chart with no axis labels]

However, it has no axis labels, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to add one.

**How do I add labels for the axes that can specify what it is that is being measured, units etc?**

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I've tried that, but it seems to affect the numbering, not the axis label itself.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be supported, I'd suggest raising this as an issue on their repo: https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues. You could maybe try supplying a custom `rootComponent`, not sure how that would interfere with the other rendering though.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/3089

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to label the y-axis

```
    <ValueAxis position="right">
      <Title text="millions" />
    </ValueAxis>
```